# Why are my Sharepoint Links missing the Tenant?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am working on an automate flow that emails a share point page to a list of subscribers whenever the page is updated.

Everything works except the links contained in the email (/page). On share point i am able to navigate to the link however in the email the page redirects me to **/sites/xxx/xxx.aspx**. It is missing the tenant information.

Is there a setting i missed or something that is preventing sharepoint from including the full link when sending the email?

I made sure the full link was typed when the hyperlink was created and am using an HTTP to share point (in automate) and inserting the "CanvasContent1" into the email. I checked the html being sent and the link title is given as the full link but the href is given as **/sites/xxx/xxx.aspx**.

Thank you for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a SharePoint page, links will be converted to relative links when the page is saved.

If you copy the page content as rendered into an email, then, yes, the tenant will not be included in the link, since the link is never intended to be used outside of the context of the page, where the link works fine.

So, you need to change your approach when emailing the page. Maybe email just a link to the page, then people can take it from there. Or, manipulate the html content in PowerAutomate and replace `/sites/xxx` with `https://Yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites.xxx`

Comment: Thank you so much. I see that extracting content from a page still needs some work. I appreciate the help with this silly problem.